# Can all EUR Nintendo 64 cartridges be set to English?

Tags: nintendo-64

I purchased Paper Mario 64 a year ago and it allowed me to set language to English.

I live in Australia and most games don't have the language select functionality they are just set at English.

I am wanting to buy Smash Bros online which is marked as NUS-006(01)EUR.

Do all EUR cartridges have language select or are there different regions?

Comment: That would depend on the cartridge, I would suspect.  Some will, like Paper Mario, but I doubt all of them will provide that option.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, NUS-006(01) is the part number of the N64 cartridge (please refer to [Maru-chang's introduction page](http://maru-chang.com/hard/nus/english.htm)), so it won't help. You have to ask the seller (if possible) to provide the game serial (in NUS-NSMx-xxx format for Smash Bros) to check out the information on that cartridge.

As for European cartridges, not all games support language-switching, however as I remembered (warning: I may be wrong, so please correct me if I did make a mistake): if the second set of the game serial ends with a P (NSMP in your case), then the language can be switched to English. You may need to double check that to make sure.